# Updating a value object from the aggregate in one-to-many relationship

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have recently dived into DDD and this question started bothering me. For example, take a look at the scenario mentioned in the following [article](https://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_3.pdf):

[image]

Let's say that a user made a mistake while adding an `EstimationLogEntry` to the `Task` aggregate, and now wants to correct that mistake. What would be the correct way of doing this? Value objects by nature don't have identifiers, they are identified by their structure. If this was a Web application, we would have to send the whole `EstimationLogEntry` value object as a request parameter, along with the new values, just so we could replace the old value object with the new one. Should `EstimationLogEntry` be an entity?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends. If it's a sequence of estimations, which you append every time, you can quite possibly envision an operation which updates the value only of the VO. This would use VO semantics (the VO is called to clone itself in-mem with the updated value on the specific property), and the command can just be the estimation (along with a Task id).

If you have an array of VO's which all semantically apply to Task (instead of just the "latest" or something)... it's a different matter. In that case, you'd probably have to send all of them in the request, and you'd have to include all properties too, but I'd say that the need to change just one, probably implies a need to reference them, which in turn implies a need to have an Entity instead of a VO.

Answer (score 1):

DDD emphasizes the Ubiquitous language and many modelling questions like this ones will derive their answer straight from that language.
First things first, if there's an aggregate that contains a value object, there's a good chance that the value object isn't directly created by the user. That is, the factory that creates the value object lives on the aggregates API. The value object(s) might even be derived directly from the aggregates state instead of from any direct method call. In this case, **do you want to just discard the aggregate and create a new one? That might make sense depending on your UL**.

In some cases, like if you have immutable value objects (based on your UL), **you could simply add a new entry into the log entry that "reverses" the old entry**. An example of this would be bank accounts and transactions. If bank accounts are aggregate roots and transactions are the value objects. If a transaction is erroneously entered, you can simply write a reversing transaction to void it.

It is definitely possible that you want to update the value object but that must make sense in your UL and it's implementation must also be framed around your UL. For example, if you have a scheduling application and an aggregate root is a person's schedule while the value objects are meetings. If a user erroneously enters a meeting, what your aggregate root should do would be to invalidate the old meeting (flip a flag, mark its state cancelled e.t.c) and  create a new one. These actions fit the UL for your scheduling app. The same thing as what you are calling "updating the entry" above.